# Could Rocket revive Groot by replanting a piece of Thor's axe handle?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, groot

In *Avengers: Infinity War* we see that

> Groot turns to dust,

but Thor's axe handle

> (made from Groot's hand) **didn't**.

Could Rocket replant a piece of the axe handle and raise a new Groot?

> Like he did at the end of *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol 1*.

Comment: Very interesting question! But I doubt anybody can answer this right now from the point of view of the MCU. I am not familiar enough with the GOTG comics to know if it's answerable from a comics point of view. For what it's worth, the Infinity Gauntlet series from which Avengers Infinity War drew inspiration did not include Groot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## *NO*

It is very subtle but Groot [plucked](https://youtu.be/QvrDFolfBLs?t=13m29s) a *seedling* before the fight. This was what allowed him to grow an offspring which is now known as Baby Groot. A simple piece of bark is not going to let Groot come back from the great beyond. There has to be intent behind the action. He probably gets parts of his body everywhere during fights but none grow into grootlings upon getting embedded in soil.

*Word of God*

That is my take on the matter. However, the word of God is much more [vague](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/05/26/avengers-directors-groot-stormbreaker-theory/):

> In a recent interview with directors Joe and Anthony Russo, the topic of Groot happened to come up, including the possibility of a new Groot spawning from Stormbreakers handle. “I don’t know if every piece of him that detaches ... can grow a future version of him, but who’s to say? That’s an interesting question," Russo told HuffingtonPost.

Comment: I would think there has to be intent. Otherwise anytime something gets hacked off of Groot, you'd eventually have a gazillion groots running around.

Comment: Yes indeed my friend @JohnP . He probably gets splinters everywhere when he fights.

Comment: @JohnP I think we could call that a Grey G̶o̶o̶  Groot Scenario.